# external_account not accepting dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, curl, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using stripe to update the card on a managed account external_account, but the error is asking for a token but the docs are saying wither token or dictionary.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_create_card

```
-d external_account={"object":"card", "exp_month":"04", "exp_year":"2019", "number":"5200828282828210"}
```

Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: number",
    "param": "number"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your example curl command doesn't work is that the Stripe API requires that the `Content-Type` header of requests sent to it be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you are sending a JSON string.

curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts/acct_XXYYZZ/external_accounts \
-u sk_test_AABBCC: \
-d external_account[object]="card" \
-d external_account[number]=5200828282828210 \
-d external_account[exp_month]=04 \
-d external_account[exp_year]=2019 \
-d external_account[cvc]=123

From the curl man-page, the "-d" switch on the curl command "Sends  the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which what you want, and the square bracket notation is how you send a hash/dictionary as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I end up getting this error `{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Requests made on behalf of a connected account must use card tokens from Stripe.js, but card details were directly provided.",
    "param": "external_account"
  }
}`

Comment: @joethemow, did you find out why you were getting the 'Request made on behalf of a connected account...' error?